# Image missing in ::after Pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a button with hover effect.

When I am applying the hover class then the image(down arrow) is missing. If I remove hover class then I can see the image.

Html code with hover class

```
<button type="submit" class="button uppercase btn-1b">home</button>
```

Html code without hover class

```
<button type="submit" class="button uppercase">home</button>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/16scmbcr/2/) - With Image but without hover effect

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/78ehmzw3/) -- With hover effect but missing the image.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define arrow image in `.button::before` pseudo-element and transitioning background in `.btn-1b:after`:

```css
.button::before {
  background-image: url("http://s12.postimg.org/63ise2fkp/button_arrow.png?noCache=1431762044");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4.1rem;
  top: 1.1rem;
  width: 8px;
}
.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.button {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #9d9368;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    width: 220px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.btn-1b:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    z-index: -1;
}
.btn-1b:hover, .btn-1b:active {
    color: #0e83cd;
}
.btn-1b:hover:after, .btn-1b:active:after {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="button uppercase btn-1b">home</button>
```

Comment: Awesome....Thank you so much. I haven't thought about before class. I used to think that :before is something where you can put the content before the text.

Comment: Well yes, before puts contents before text, but you anyway position it absolutely, so it doesn't matter where it is.

Comment: ahh yes that makes sense. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: if I want to change the white down arrow to some other arrow then should I use button:hover:before?